# How to return non-existent rows in sql?

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables, left table contains the primary key and if there isn't any entry in the right table then how can I display the values only from left table and showing a blank for the values which were to be fetched from right table?
 I have tried left join but still can't display such a thing.

Comment: Tag your DBMS. Post your code that didn't work, this sounds like a very simple left join query.

Comment: Please provide some schema information and the query, a left join should be suitable, so you most likely have something wrong in the query itself.

Comment: As already said, a `LEFT JOIN` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Left join](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_leftouterjoin.html) should work, please check your syntax

```
select table_1.*,table_2.* 
from table_1
left join
table_2 
on (table_1.column_name = table_2.column_name)
```